# How to submit a form on a page right after it loads

Tags: php, javascript, session

I am creating a page which has two forms (signup.php)

screenshot hosted at:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/acZNw.png

The first form has a textbox to search students by id (It includes the UIN and the Search Button).

After submitting first form a second form with result is displayed on the same page. The second form also has a textbox to update the students information. Then on submitting the second form, an update is made to the database via a separate php file.

```
<FORM class= "student_update" NAME ="form2" METHOD ="POST" ACTION = "update_DB.php">
```

Content of update_DB.php after the database transaction.

```
    $_SESSION['update_uin'] = $update_uin;
header('Location: signup.php');
```

After the update is made I wish to display the updated employee information. 
To do this I was planning on populating the ID search field in first form and submitting it on page load so that the table will be displayed with new information.
Is this the correct method to go about it?
I am maintaining the employee-id in the session between the signup.php file and the database update php file. I do not wish to transfer the UIN via $_GET

Thanks a lot in advance. Extremely sorry for the unclear question.

Comment: Did you try it ? What's question here ? Try it & then if you face some problem, do ask here. p.s you can simply show update value by searching from ID - it's pretty simple.

Comment: Updated the question. Could not embed the image of the webpage that I created so provided a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirect to second form redirect to either first form or an other one to show update user using `$_post` e.g `.../updatedform.php?ID=$userId`

Read documentation for using `post` here: 
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_post.asp

A good tip is to use AJAX and display popup with updated value there, after database is updated.

p.s you can also use php `$_Get` method and parse URL parameters.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but the update_db.php file just handles database transaction and then redirects back to signup.php

Comment: I also wrote a tip - use AJAX & show updated info in popup there. That's Good thing. p.s Please Vote UP for the answer and accept it - Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Have your second form return a redirect to `firstform.php?search=$id` (replace `search` with whatever the form field name is for the ID search field).

The form should use `$_REQUEST['search']` to get the form input, so that it allows either a POST field or a URL parameter like this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but I have cleared up the question. The question basically boils down to "On redirect from update_DB.php to signup.php, how to populate the UIN textbox with $_SESSION['update_uin'] and press Search button on page load"

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<form id="first_form">
    <input type="text"...../>
    <input type="submit" id="submit_button" />
</form>
```

Have the first form showing normally, and the second form hidden.

```
<form id="second_form" style="display:none;">
    <input type="text"...../>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

you can submit the first form with ajax, and on the click of the submit button, show the second form like this:

**Javascript (in jquery)**

```
$("#submit_button").click(function(){
    $("#second_form").show();
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but I have cleared up the question. The question basically boils down to "On redirect from update_DB.php to signup.php, how to populate the UIN textbox with $_SESSION['update_uin'] and press Search button on page load"